# Reading range of items from plist in correct order

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, plist

In cocos2d for iPhone, is there a way to turn the following into a for-loop, such that a range of values can be specified? At the moment, it simply goes through all values (but not in the correct order).

```
// plist file 
NSString * file                 = @"myproperties";
NSString * dictPath             = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file 
                                                         ofType:@"plist"];

// get dictionary
NSMutableDictionary * dictPlist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                                   initWithContentsOfFile:dictPath];

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dictPlist objectEnumerator ];
id value;
while ((value = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    CCLog("Test: @%", [value objectForKey:@"Name"]);
}
```

I would like to be able to only print a range of items, say 10 to 15 (in the order in which the data are in the list). How can that be achieved?

---

**EDIT:** How do I need to change the following list, if I want to use an array instead of the dict (to keep the order)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>personTom</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Tom</string>
        <key>Age</key>
        <integer>30</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>personJames</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>James</string>
        <key>Age</key>
        <integer>45</integer>
    </dict>
    <!-- (...) -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over NSDictionary elements gives you the elements in random order. A dictionary is not sorted.

If sorting is important to you, use NSArray to store your elements and sort it. Alternatively you can read all the dictionary's keys and put them in a temporary NSArray, then sort that array, iterate over the keys in the array to obtain the dictionary's values in sorted order.

Comment: to spell it out : NSArray *_sortedKeys=[[NSArray arrayWithArray:[list allKeys]] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:) ];. Then iterate over _sortedKeys, fetching the objects in the correct order. Even if you dont like the answer, it is correct!